# primefaces use p:dataTable,draggableColumns = "true" and use dynamic columns, but not work

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cnbz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU1FL.png)

why i use draggableColumns and dynamic columns，the dynamic columns just work first time，when I update the page，it can not work

after try，I find do not use draggableColumns，the dynamic columns will work，but WHY??
Please tell me，thank you everybody

Comment: Please don't add code in images. And please note that not all data table features can be combined per se.